# Difference between always @ block and @ statement in Verilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, synthesis

I have not across the statement `@(posedge clk)` before. I would like to know how this statement is different from the `always @(posedge clk)` block which I am familiar with.

If I use a sensitivity list in a task for a Finite State Machine synthesis without always block; How is this different from a task with always block and sensitivity list?

As I understand both `@` and `always @` have the same functionality as both of them are **always** sensitive to the changes in the sensitivity list. Are there any differences with respect to simulation or synthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `always @(posedge clk)` statement is actually a combination of two statements:

The `always` procedural block:

```
always ... begin
    //Body of 'always' block
end
```

And a sensitivity list:

```
@(posedge clk)      - At the positive edge of clk
@(signal or signal) - Any change in listed signals
@*                  - Any change to any signal used as an input to the block
```

When using Verilog for testbenches/simulation (this is not just SystemVerilog behaviour), you can use the always block on its own, for example

```
always begin
    #5 clk = !clk; //Create a clock of period 10 units
end
```

You can also use the sensitivity list on its own, in the form of a [**Procedural Timing Control**](https://www.hdlworks.com/hdl_corner/verilog_ref/items/ProceduralTimingControl.htm):

```
initial begin
    @(posedge clk);           //Wait for a pos-edge of the clock
    reset = 1;                //Assert reset
    repeat(2) @(posedge clk); //Wait for two pos-edge of clock
    reset = 0;                /Adeassert reset
end
```

Essentially this allows you to perform a sequence of test events based on say, a clock edge.

---

As far as I'm aware you can't use the procedural timing control for synthesis - instead a state machine or similar would be built within an edge sensitive always block.